# how to develop pypi package for python3 and python2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip, pypi

Can anyone point me toward a tutorial explaining how to implement a pypi package with support for both python2 and python3?  Google did not provide an answer so this is my next option!  Thank you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is hardly an enhanced Google for finding tutorials.

Comment: I mainly stated that so people wouldn't think I didn't try to find a solution already.  I also search SO for an answer to this question but I did not find one.  I suspect this is a question many developers would have for developing their first pypi package.  Many pypi packages support 2 & 3 but there are still many important ones that do not (Fabric for instance).  I don't know why this is but I want to develop one that supports both.  This a legitimate question about a problem that may prevent many developers from trying to contribute to Python.

Comment: To make your project be single-source Python 2/3 compatible, see [Porting Python 2 Code to Python 3](https://docs.python.org/dev/howto/pyporting.html)

Comment: In addition to the 2 bridge modules listed in Porting Python 2 Code to Python 3 (see above for link, I recommend it also), pypi also has the 'six' module (6=2*3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with many tutorials out there on Python packing is that they try to cover a lot of ground, with *so many* possible options. When I was at this stage, I found them very confusing, given the number of variables you might encounter, and the amount of Python historical packaging issues some of them still lead you through.

My recommended is to instead take a module that you know runs well across Python 2 and Python 3, and that installs to PyPI, and study it. Modify it, replacing parts with your own desired code and module configuration. You can always compare what you know works to what you currently have, giving you a solid base for testing and exploration.

I unhumbly offer you my [intspan](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/intspan) module as one such starting point. It runs across a great many Python implementations, including 2 and 3. It has extensive test coverage. And its source is [readily available](https://bitbucket.org/jeunice/intspan) for cloning. If not `intspan`, take some other module as your starting point, rather than an abstract tutorial.

Comment: Does anyone create a separate implementation for py3 and py2 within the same package in place of using six?

Comment: Yes they do. Major approaches: 1. use a compatibility library (e.g. `six`, `nine`, or something module-specific) 2. filter code (e.g. `2to3`) or 3. side-by-side implementations, conditionally imported based on which Python interpreter is running. I have used a combination of 1 and 3. IME, 1 is preferable, though 3 sometimes seems or is needed.