# How to package a python module for 2.7 & 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, packaging

I've written a Python module that works fine in Python 2 & 3, but requires the `mock` package in Python 2 (it's part of `unittest` in Python 3).  Ideally, I'd prefer *not* to have the dependency on mock for Python 3 users, but how do I do that?

I considered setting `install_requires=` dynamically based on something like `six.PY2` or even checking for an `ImportError` on `import unittest.mock`, but as I'd be issuing `python setup.py bdist_wheel` while running *inside a Python3 environment*, I'm afraid that these values would always evaluate based on the building environment, rather than the installing one.

So, is there an official way to do this sort of thing?

> Note: I'm aware that I can have a dependency on mock for Python3, but I'd rather not have a superfluous depedency if I can help it.  Besides, I'm sure there are other packages out there that ship separately for PY2 vs. PY3 that might be relevant here.

Comment: Sorry, I can't answer your question, but there appears to be some useful info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242087/how-to-develop-pypi-package-for-python3-and-python2